# Number Type Schema not updating

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that let's you give fame points to users as well as currency, currency works just fine and it updates whenever someone sends a message with a 1 minute cooldown. however I'm having problems with my fame schema. the bot creates a new schema if there's not an already existing one without problem and it also displays the amount correctly, however, when you click the button to give someone a Fame point, it doesn't, it stays at 0. I'm probably missing something simple but I can't seem to find it, here's the code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed,ButtonInteraction} = require('discord.js');
const Fame = require('../../schemas/fame');

module.exports = {
    data: {
        name: `yes-fame`
    },
    async execute (interaction, client) {
            const user = require('../../commands/entertainment/givefame')
            const fameProfile = await client.createFame(user)
            try {
                await Fame.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: fameProfile._id}, { $inc: { amount: 1 } });
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            const userEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`<:fame:952026535756435536> Fame Point Given`)
            .setDescription(`${interaction.user} has given 1 fame point to ${user} `)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor("#00FF00")
            .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [userEmbed]});

        }
    };
```

(the cooldown is low because I'm not entirely sure how long to make it yet)

Here is the code for the Fame Schema.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fameSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    guildId: String,
    memberId: String,
    amount: { type: Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Fame', fameSchema, 'fame-points');
```

and here's the code for the const "user", it's either the user mentioned or if none, the one using the slash command.

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser("user") || interaction.user;
```

And here's the createFame function

```js
const Fame = require('../schemas/fame');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = (client) => {
    client.createFame = async (member) => {
      let fameProfile = await Fame.findOne({ memberId: member.id, guildId: member.guild.id });
      if (fameProfile) {
          return fameProfile;
       } else {
           fameProfile = await new Fame({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), 
            guildId: member.guild.id,
            memberId: member.id,

           });
           await fameProfile.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
           return fameProfile;
       }
    };
};
```

I thought that maybe there was an error in the user const itself or when importing it but I made the bot send a test message using that const and it is getting the user no problem so idk what's wrong.

it shows the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at Client.client.createFame (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\functions\createFame.js:6:89)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\buttons\info\yes-fame.js:10:46)
at Object.execute (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\events\interactionCreate.js:25:26)
at Client. (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\functions\handleEvents.js:8:58)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `$inc` property/method/wtv in mongoose model. Try this-

```
await Fame.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: fameProfile._id}, { $inc: { amount: 1 } });
```

Comment: I think I found the problem, I forgot to assign the Fame event to the button, I did it   but now it says it cannot read properties of undefined (reading id), I updated the code in the question

Comment: this is the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at Client.client.createFame (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\functions\createFame.js:6:89)
    at Object.execute(C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\buttons\info\yes-fame.js:10:46)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\desktop\bot\src\events\interactionCreate.js:25:26)
    at Client.<anonymous>